# Build using MSBuild with web.config transforms in both local and azure devops environments

Tags: .net, msbuild, azure-devops, web-config, cakebuild

I am trying to build both locally and on an Azure DevOps build pipeline (which is utilizing a Cake build script) an ASP.NET Framework project within a solution and publish it. Our old version was built with the following command:

```
MSBUILD /verbosity:%VERBOSITY% "%WORKSPACE%\src\Foundation\Security\OurProduct.SAML/OurProduct.SAML.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=%CONFIGURATION% /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PublishProfile=%CONFIGURATION% /p:publishUrl=%WORKSPACE%\samlbuild\_PublishedWebsites\OurProduct.SAML
```

I added it into Cake and made lots of different edits in my test. Here is the current version:

```
MSBuild(
    SAMLProject, 
    new MSBuildSettings()
        .WithProperty("Configuration", configuration)
        .WithProperty("DeployOnBuild", "true")
         //.WithProperty("PublishProfile", configuration)
        .WithProperty("WebPublishMethod", "FileSystem")
        .WithProperty("OutDir", SAMLDeployDirectory)
    );
```

By removing or commenting the PublishProfile line, I can build locally, but I cannot build on the VS2017 Hosted agent on Azure DevOps. I get the following error on the hosted server:

```
"D:\a\1\s\PPUXL\src\Foundation\Security\OurProduct.SAML\OurProduct.SAML.csproj" (Build target) (1) ->
(Web_config_AfterBuild target) -> 
  D:\a\1\s\PPUXL\src\Foundation\Security\OurProduct.SAML\OurProduct.SAML.csproj(511,5): error : Could not write Destination file: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\1\s\PPUXL\src\Foundation\Security\OurProduct.SAML\bin\Web.config'.
```

I saw this website (https://blog.todotnet.com/2013/11/deploy-website-to-windows-azure-with-web-config-transformations/) and tried their solution along with some other solutions I saw here on Stack Overflow. When I specify PublishProfile, it does not build locally so I don't dare push it to origin to test on the server. I get the following error locally when specifying the "Dev" configuration profile as the publish profile:

```
"C:\git\OurProduct\PPUXL\src\Foundation\Security\OurProduct.SAML\OurProduct.SAML.csproj" (Build target) (1) ->
(WebFileSystemPublish target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(93,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\jenkins\current\Stage\samlidp". Could not f
ind a part of the path 'D:\jenkins\current\OurProduct\samlidp'. [C:\git\OurProduct\PPUXL\src\Foundation\Security\OurProduct.SAML\OurProduct.SAML.csproj]
```

I have all of the configuration files and their transforms in project's root directory. So the questions I have are:

1. What am I missing in my Cake script?
2. Do I need to change my project file or transform web configurations?
3. How do I build my code out of its folder but output it to a directory of my choosing both locally and on the Azure DevOps server so I can create a publish artifact on AzDo?